# I can't update a users info to add a password reset link

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, jwt, lodash

I'm having trouble getting a variable within a database user to update using lodash. It seems to update in one route (password in /resetpassword) but not in the other. (resetLink in /forgotpassword)

I need to have "resetLink" update to the new token generated by JWT, in order to create a link to reset the users password.

**/forgotpassword**

```
router.put('/forgotpassword', (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body;
  if (!email) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Please enter all fields" });
  } else {
    // Find existing User by email address
    User.findOne({ email }).then((user) => {
      if (!user) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "That email doesn't exist with us..." });
      const payload = {
        id: user._id,
      }
      const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
      const token = jwt.sign(payload, secret, {
        expiresIn: '15m'
      });
      const obj = {
        resetLink: token
      }
      console.log("obj is " + JSON.stringify(obj));
      console.log("User is " + user);
      user = _.extend(user, obj);
      user.save((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(400).json({{ error: "Something went wrong..." + err }});
        } else {
          return res.status(200).json({ msg: "Success! These should match: TOKEN - " + token + " / RESET LINK - " + user.resetLink })
        }
      })
    });
  };
});
```

**/resetpassword**

```
router.put('/resetpassword', (req, res) => {
  const { resetLink, newPass } = req.body;
  if (resetLink) {
    jwt.verify(resetLink, process.env.JWT_SECRET, function (err, decodedData) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(401).json({ msg: "Incorrect token or it is expired." });
      }
      User.findOne({ resetLink }, (err, user) => {
        if (err || !user) {
          return res.status(400).json({ error: "User with this token doesn't exist" });
        }
        // newPass will be hashed by jwt eventually
        const obj = {
          password: newPass
        }

        user = _.extend(user, obj);
        user.save((err, result) => {
          if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Reset password error" });
          } else {
            return res.status(200).json({ message: "Your password has been changed" });
          }
        })
      })
    })
  } else {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: "Authentication error!" });
  }
});
```

**Mongoose User model**

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  register_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  resetLink: {
    data: String,
    default: '',
  }
});
```

As always I appreciate any help at all. Thanks.

EDIT: Here is the returned error -

```
"error": "Something went wrong...ValidationError: resetLink: Cast to Object failed for value \"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVmM2JjN2MwNGVmMmRkNGE2ODkwZDEwYiIsImlhdCI6MTU5Nzc1NDY2MCwiZXhwIjoxNTk3NzU1NTYwfQ.BL8yYsqk2A5hGlNTPa2AxtD_iJ1lWELiCgtpcCkFB6I\" at path \"resetLink\""
```

Answer (score 0):

My Schema was off. Apologies.

```
resetLink: {
data: String,
default: '',
}
```

Should be:

```
resetLink: {
Type: String,
default: '',
}
```